# Creating widgets in a different class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have the mainwindow in the 'DataClass'.How can I create widgets in another class(the HelloClass)

test.py

```
import sys
import label
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class DataClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DataClass, self).__init__()
        self.window()

    def window(self):
        ex=label.HelloClass(self)
        ex.print_label()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ob=DataClass()
    ob.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

and this is the 'label.py' file:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class HelloClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def print_label(self):
        self.la=QtGui.QLabel("hello",self)
        self.la.move(300,100)
        self.la.show()

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class HelloClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def print_label(self):
        self.la=QtGui.QLabel("hello",self)
        self.la.move(300,100)
        self.la.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two `QMainWindow` class, you should just not inherit from `QMainWindow` on `HelloClass`. And if you are setting parent to label then set it your `DataClass` which is your `QMainWindow`.

```
class HelloClass(object):
    def print_label(self, parent):
        self.la = QtGui.QLabel("hello", parent)
        self.la.move(300, 100)
        self.la.show()

class DataClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DataClass, self).__init__()
        self.window()

    def window(self):
        ex = label.HelloClass()
        ex.print_label(self)
```

But to be honest, the best way to create GUI using PyQt is to use QtDesigner. Create your .ui file with QtDesigner and then create .py file with command `pyuic4 your.ui -o ui_your.py`.

-- **UPDATE** --

Your controller class for using gui created by QtDesigner would look like this:

```
from ui_objects import Ui_Objects  # this is class created with QtDesigner, name of class is a 'Ui_' + name of main Object in QtDesigner    

class Objects(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Objects()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    # then you can add your own code, in example connect your own methods to actions for widgets
```

Comment: I thought of using QtDesigner, but someone told that you can't make your own slots using it.

Comment: Well you would need to code some things yourself anyway. QtDesigner isn't meant for creating whole app from scratch with no need to code. It just speed up process of creating GUI a lot. But you still need to code lot of things yourself. And then you can write your own slots too. Look at my updated answer.